# Rails ActiveRecord where condition eager load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, eager-loading

I have a situation where I need to access 2 databases to construct a certain data set. This is a ruby code using ActiveRecord gem. Not RAILS. I am dealing with legacy databases and developing an extraction script using Ruby.

From the first db

```
users = db1.table_db1.where("user_id in (?)", user_ids)
txn = db2.table_db2.all
```

After this I am referencing users

```
users.each do |user|
   # do something
end
```

I get an exception as below when trying to execute the users.each.

If I am accessing the `users` variable prior to access the db2 then this problem no longer exist. Looks like this is related to eager load?

```html
Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `query'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `block in execute'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `execute'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:228:in `execute'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:232:in `exec_query'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:240:in `select'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:24:in `select_all'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in `select_all'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:611:in `exec_queries'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:493:in `load'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:238:in `to_a'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
file-exporter.rb:179:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
/Users/devuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
```

Comment: Are you joining those somewhere in your code? You show very little code so it's hard to tell if something else is going on. Is this all your code? If you do just the `txn = db2.table_db2.all` part of the script with nothing else, does it throw an error?

Comment: The problem might be the `.each` itself, but without showing us what is happening in the `.each` block, we'll never be able to guess. What if you just leave the inside of the each block blank and don't actually do anything in there? Does it still error?

Answer (score 1):

Not a ton of info to go on, but if it seems to be a load problem, then load the two tables:

```
users = db1.table_db1.where("user_id in (?)", user_ids).load
txn = db2.table_db2.all.load
```

Comment: Probably because it's a script using ActiveRecord rather than a standard Rails app. Maybe because of the multiple handles. Good to know it worked. Can you "accept" the answer so it shows up as answered?

Comment: I did accept the answer. "Maybe because of multiple handles" is the part that has been unsettling for me. May be some one else can shed some more light on this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It look as if you clicked the "Upvote" button, as it has a "1" for up-votes, when you click "accept answer" then it will show a green checkmark. Thanks.